# Questions on trading card layouts

Tags: discussion, on-topic, off-topic

I'm in the process of designing the cards for a card game I've made.

Are questions related to this on topic Here?

Comment: What sort of questions would you be asking? We're not limited to digital here, in fact there is a [tag:physical] tag that lists questions around physical items. But they still need to be UX questions.

Comment: I mostly want to ask about symbol usage and placement. Does it show what I need it to. It's there too much information etc.

Comment: That may be in-scope, yes. However bear in mind that asking for icon suggestions isn't really on topic, and nor is a general UI review (or in your case a card review). If you have specific issues then that's fine because they may be relevant to many other people (how to layout certain elements etc) but a broad 'Is my design good' isn't really of use to others.

Comment: As long as it's a UX question, everything from card games, to toilet handle designs are on topic.

Comment: I like how people are answering the question in the comments because they don't want their answer down voted.

Answer (score 1):

They can be.  If you have questions about usability (how users interact with your solution), then yes.  If you have programming questions or errors in your code, you'd be best turning to the Programming page or Stack Overflow.